# Django list of json objects

Tags: python, django

I have a django backend and from my view I want to return a list of json objects.

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_analytics(request):
    # Number of users who dogged in once to our system today
    login_count=  User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=
        timezone.now().date()).count() # returns int
    finished_count = Exercise_state.objects.filter(exercise_id=7, progress=2).count()
    # returns int

    count_list=[]
    count_list.append(login_count)
    count_list.append(finished_count)

    data = {}
    data['login_count'] = login_count
    data['finish_count'] = finished_count
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    return Response(json_data)
```

This returns `"{\"finish_count\": 1, \"login_count\": 2}"` However what I want is something like `[{"login_count": 2, "finished_count": 3}]`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JsonResponse` instead, to properly parse the `json` object:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

then, you can use your original `dict` object:

```
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `JsonResponse`. But if you are going to use it you don't need `json.dumps(data)`, `JsonResponse` dose it for you. Quoting from [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

> ```
> >>> from django.http import JsonResponse
> >>> response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
> >>> response.content
> b'{"foo": "bar"}'
> ```

If you are using django < 1.7, do(it's still available in later versions, but `JsonResponse` makes it eaiser):

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```